# How to communicate Android app to mysql DB via a web service?

Tags: java, android, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis

I am making an Android app for Smart Shopping system. I want to:-

1. Make a web app which can create QR code of info about products (i.e. QR code having unique ID of products). All this info should be stored in MySQL
2. This QR code will contain a URL like 
   http://localhost:8080/Mysupermarket/index.jsp/pid=1
   (Something like this)
3. The customer will scan QR code and will be directed to this page and somehow he should fetch all details stores in DB for that product.

4.All this data should be then converted to string so that my app can convert to speech

What have I done so far?

http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-mysql-client.html

I followed this tutorial which uses SOAP web service. But when I run webapp on server and click on listservice, it threw this exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
        at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:60)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4997)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5289)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
        ... 24 more

    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
    SEVERE: Servlet [AxisAdminServlet] in web application [/WebApp] threw load() exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
        at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:60)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4997)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5289)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\webapps\docs
    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\webapps\docs has finished in 47 ms
    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\webapps\examples
    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\webapps\examples has finished in 563 ms
    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\webapps\host-manager
    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\webapps\host-manager has finished in 46 ms
    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\webapps\manager
    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\webapps\manager has finished in 32 ms
    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\webapps\ROOT
    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
    INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\webapps\ROOT has finished in 62 ms
    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 4629 ms
    [INFO] Clustering has been disabled
    [WARN] Unable to instantiate deployer org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer; see debug logs for more details
    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
        ... 30 more

    Apr 24, 2016 8:48:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet AxisServlet
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How do I fix it?
Also please suggest some good tutorials on how to connect Android app to a web service. 
Most of them are using PHP. I want to use Java.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This error look as the build path problem. You must add dependency to application;
Correct dependency is;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
        <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I did that. But now it shows faulty service, when i run it

Comment: I fixed it by downloading the latest schema 2.2.1